# Querying SQL Database using LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, linq

```
 SELECT Meter.SerialNumber as serial, 
 SupplyPoint.Id as supplypoint,
 SupplyType.Id as supplytype,
 SupplyType.Name as supplytypename
 FROM Meter
 INNER JOIN SupplyPoint ON Meter.SupplyPointId = SupplyPoint.Id
 INNER JOIN SupplyType ON SupplyPoint.SupplyTypeId = SupplyType.Id;
```

I have this query so that I might find the Supply Type of a meter based on it's serial. So far I've written this function:

```
var query = from meters in db.Meters
join supplyPoint in db.SupplyPoints on meters.SupplyPointId
equals supplyPoint.Id
join supplyType in db.SupplyTypes on supplyPoint.SupplyTypeId equals             
supplyType.Id
select new { serial = meters.SerialNumber, type = supplyType.Name };
foreach (var meter in query)
    {
        if (meter.serial == serial)
            return meter.type;
    }
return "Meter Type Not Specified";`
```

So I call FindType(string serial) and it returns the type. Can anyone suggest better code for converting such a query? Any directions on where to learn more about LINQ are welcome too.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does your database table look like? Have you set up a data context using Entity Framework?

Comment: Your conversion looks good, but normally you would use LINQ to find your answer as well: `var ans = (from meter in query where meter.serial == serial select meter).SingleOrDefault(); return (meter == null) ? "Meter Type Not Specified" : meter.type;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are up for reading up quite a bit of material before you should get started.

1. Read about entity framework [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937723(v=vs.113).aspx).
2. Read about LINQ to SQL
   [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx).

Hopefully, once you have you will realize that your problem boils down to the following code.

```
var result = context.YourTable.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Field == searchValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much about what you are working with there's little that can be done to give you concrete help. First you want to get familiar with translating the sql statement to LINQ.

LINQ has a query syntax that starts with the from because that is how to define the datasource. `SELECT FirstName FROM Authors` becomes

```
from auth in db.Authors
select auth.FirstName
```

Where db is a reference to a datacontext as suggested in slugster's comment.

You can look for more information on linq [at the following url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries)